# How to group array by DateTime in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have PHP Array as a log from some function, and I am preparing Date wise chart for the same,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 03-08-15 12:07:16 PM
    [1] => 03-08-15 01:54:16 PM
    [2] => 03-08-15 02:18:35 PM
    [3] => 03-08-15 06:32:17 PM
    [4] => 04-08-15 11:40:25 AM
    [5] => 04-08-15 01:47:23 PM
    [6] => 04-08-15 02:13:31 PM
    [7] => 04-08-15 05:46:10 PM
    [8] => 05-08-15 11:36:20 AM
    [9] => 05-08-15 01:43:04 PM
    [10] => 05-08-15 02:25:14 PM
    [11] => 05-08-15 06:06:24 PM
    [12] => 06-08-15 11:25:31 AM
    [13] => 06-08-15 01:52:32 PM
    ... and so on
)
```

I want to re-order it by Date wise, where key the date and value is inner array which holds all the entries of that particular day.

```
Array
(
     [03-08-15] => Array
                   (
                        [0] => 12:07:16 PM
                        [1] => 01:54:16 PM
                        [2] => 02:18:35 PM
                        [3] => 06:32:17 PM
                   )
     [04-08-15] => Array
                   (
                        [0] => 11:40:25 AM
                        [1] => 01:47:23 PM
                        [2] => 02:13:31 PM
                        [3] => 05:46:10 PM
                   )
     [05-08-15] => Array
                   (
                        [0] => 11:40:25 AM
                        [1] => 01:47:23 PM
                        .....
                   )
    and so on...
)
```

So far I have tried with

```
$tempArray = array();
foreach ($allEntries as $entry) {
    $date = new DateTime($entry);
    $tempArray[$date->format('m-d-y')] = $date->format('h:i:s A');
}
print_r($tempArray);
```

Comment: Can you share your code you tried?? @Shadab

Comment: Loop through the array, and split the entry into a date and time. Check whether the output array has an entry for the date, otherwise add one containing an empty array. Then push the time onto that sub-array.

Comment: @SubinThomas, check now.

Comment: close enough,  `$tempArray[$date->format('m-d-y')][]`

Comment: @Federico `$tempArray[$date->format('m-d-y')] = this part should be sub-array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far I have tried with

Close enough, you miss the `[]`

```
$dates = [
    '03-08-15 12:07:16 PM',
    '03-08-15 01:54:16 PM',
    '03-08-15 02:18:35 PM',
    '03-08-15 06:32:17 PM',
    '04-08-15 11:40:25 AM',
    '04-08-15 01:47:23 PM',
    '04-08-15 02:13:31 PM',
    '04-08-15 05:46:10 PM',
    '05-08-15 11:36:20 AM',
    '05-08-15 01:43:04 PM',
    '05-08-15 02:25:14 PM',
    '05-08-15 06:06:24 PM',
    '06-08-15 11:25:31 AM',
    '06-08-15 01:52:32 PM',
];

$newDates = [];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $dataTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y H:i:s A', $date);
    $newDates[$dataTime->format('d-m-y')][] = $dataTime->format('H:i:s A');
}

var_dump($newDates);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aO9ZM).